# Почему этот js-скрипт не работает?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Между  тегами script нужно сделать так, чтоб выводились данные (data)...Если отдельно подключать, то все работает, но мне нужно, чтоб в между ОДНИМИ тегами script был ВЕСЬ код...Подскажите почему оно не работает или КАК мне сделать, чтоб весь код работал между одними тегами script

```
<div id="placeholder"></div> <!--здесь  НЕ выводит -->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
    var data={"firstName":"Ray"};
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.firstName;
</script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>  <!-- и здесь НЕ выводит -->
```

Код ниже рабочий, но НЕ удовлетворяет указанным требованиям

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var data={"firstName":"Ray"};
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerText=data.firstName;
</script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: А зачем минусовать? Если Вы НЕ знаете ответ на этот вопрос, то минусовать вопрос нужно сразу? Я написал этот вопрос потому, что он актуален в данный момент для меня и нужен неординарный подход в его решении...

Comment: ЗНАЮ, что нельзя!!!! но это НУЖНО!!!!Спасибо Вам за внимание, похоже Вашего креатива хватает только на то, чтоб ставить минусы!!!!

Comment: а чего Вы минусы ставите?Вы разве никогда не делали НЕОБЫЧНЫЕ тестовые задания для IT-компаний?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел решение.....глупое, но работает, а главное удовлетворяет трребованиям вопроса:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
<?php echo '</Script>'; ?>
<?php echo '<script>'; ?>
    var data={"firstName":"Ray"};
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerText=data.firstName;
</script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: и какой в нем смысл? Это равносильно тому, что бы просто создать два тега script, как Вам все советовали. Откройте страницу в браузере и увидите просто два тега script

Comment: @Igor Lut, я писал в вопросе, что нужно именно между одними тегами,а что между двумя у меня и так работает...а меня начали минусить...задание мне такое дали, условие такое, чтоб ВСЁ содержимое заключалось между одними тегами!Как будто никто, из поставивших минус, никогда не делал подобные задания...

Comment: `<?php echo '</script>'; ?>` превратиться просто в `</script>`. Это АБСОЛЮТНО тоже, если бы вы просто вставили `</script>`. В конечном итоге у Вас два тега script, а не однин

Comment: @Igor Lut я знаю, так и нужно, чтоб браузер прочитал именно ТАК!!!задание,чтоб скрипт заключался между одними тегами script и его можно было вставить куда угодно, чтоб он был независим ни от чего!

Comment: Вы, наверное, не понимаете, но Ваш ответ превратиться в ответ, который Вам дал Назар Калитюк. В них НЕТ разницы. Ладно, Вам виднее, бессмысленный спор.

Comment: @Igor Lut, прочитайте вопрос повнимательнее! там  ответ Назара написал!и я с казал, что ТАК работает! И это заключается в двух тегах, а НЕ в одном! Мне нужно было, чтоб в браузере подключались нужные библиотеки, а в html-коде был только открывающий и закрывающий тег script

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65998/discussion-between--and-igor-lut).

Answer (score 4):

Потому что нельзя в 1 теге `script` и jquery поключить и код выполнить.

```html
<div id="placeholder"></div> <!--здесь  НЕ выводит -->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var data={"firstName":"Ray"};
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerText=data.firstName;
</script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>  <!-- и здесь НЕ выводит -->
```

Comment: Я не до конца понял, что пользователь имел ввиду под "Если отдельно подключать"

Comment: @Назар Калитюк , я ж поэтому и спрашиваю КАК мне сделать между одними тегами script...прочитайте внимательно вопрос - там я говорил, что если jquery  подключить  отдельно, то работает

Comment: @Александр Тогда вставьте в тело script все содержимое файла jquery-1.7.1.min.js, а дальше пишите свой код.

Comment: @IgorLut, спасибо за подсказку!!!ЕДИНСТВЕННОЕ подходящее решение !Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер, т.к вы используете JQuery, то можете использовать другой синтаксис

```
$("#placeholder").html(data.firstName)
```